# Using abstract factory as injectionfactory in Unity?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, enterprise-library, abstract-factory

I have an abstract factory registered for injection in some controller instances.
Can I register that abstract factory and use it as an injection factory?

This is what I have:

```
public interface ILevelFactory
{
    Levels Create();
}

.RegisterType<ILevelFactory, LevelFactory>()
.RegisterType<Levels>(new InjectionFactory((c) => StaticLevelFactory.GetLevels()))
```

Desired situation:

```
.RegisterType<ILevelFactory, LevelFactory>()
.RegisterType<Levels>(*** look up and use ILevelFactory ***)
```

In short, I want to get rid of the StaticLevelFactory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your ILevelFactory is properly registered:

```
RegisterType<Levels>(new InjectionFactory((c) => c.Resolve<ILevelFactory>().GetLevels()))
```